# postfix-how to set header_checks after always_add_missing_headers

Tags: postfix-mta

I want to check header after add missing headers.

main.cf:

```
always_add_missing_headers = yes
```

header_checks:

```
# 2022-10-25 14:21:34.371985 
/^Message-ID:/i PREPEND X-MY-HEADER: HAHA
# ------------------------------
/^To:.*6@test.com./ DISCARD
```